Excel isnt working properly after python function is started
I have a Python application that can create a graph based on input that the user enters into a form that is created via Tkinter. This application is actually made as an Excel addin. It works by creating a custom addin via xlwings and creating a custom ribbon with a button via RibbonXEditor. When the user presses this button, the python function show_form is launched via the VBA function, which actually displays the form. And now the problem is that when the form is displayed, then Excel does not work properly, it is not possible to write in the cells, I have to close the form and only then it works normally, is there any way to fix it?Here is for example the VBA code than is launching the python function.
Sub show_form(control As IRibbonControl)
Dim mymodule As String
mymodule = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, _
        (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
RunPython "import " & mymodule & ";" & _
    mymodule & ".show_form()"

End Sub

Can you paste the python code for show_form in mymodule too?

Probably you just need to show the form non-modal.

Okay here is the show_form function: pastebin.com/R6C8UrHV . Cant send it here because it is quite long BTW sorry for messy code. @rachel

Thanks for uploading the code! but I am having a hard time figuring out what is relevant and what is not relevant. Hopefully someone else see this post and help you if it is urgent. I think you need someone more technical and more familiar with Tkinter. so it is better you remove all those statistics and distribution -related the code and create an easier to read reproducible sample.

I dont think it is because of the tkinter, because even when i add plotting graph in show_form for example def show_form():
x = np.arange(-5,5,0.01)
y = stats.t.pdf(x,df=5)
plt.plot(x,y,color='blue')
plt.show()When the plot window is opened excel just doesnt work properly when i close it works, i think it might be something with VBA but i dont know

Thank you for making things much easier! Yes, it is VBA. but I just tried, removing control As IRibbonControl works. e.g. Sub show_form()     mymodule = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))     RunPython "import " & mymodule & ";" & mymodule & ".show_form()" End Sub

According to this post, we cannot manipulate Excel ribbons through xlwings. you probably have to create a button, and link that to Sub show_form().
